# calling referenceSizeForFooterInSection without calling reloadData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uicollectionview

Is there a way so that I can make UICollectionView to reload the footer section, i.e: call referenceSizeForFooterInSection of the UICollectionView without actually calling reloadData as a whole?

In my referenceSizeForFooterInSection i have a flag that determines what the height of the footer view is.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `invalidateLayout` on your `UICollectionViewLayout` will force a recalculation and adjust the sizing of it's elements

Answer (score 0):

a hack could be to put an empty section at the end and use reloadSections to load only that last section which will reload its footer.